# How can I export permanently the PATH setting when I restart my machine?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, path

I use this command in Linux but it doesn't work when I restart my machine

```
export PATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH"
export MANPATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/share/man:$MANPATH"
export INFOPATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/share/info:$INFOPATH"
```

How can I make these settings permanent (across reboots)?

Comment: Put it in your `.profile` or `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`.

Comment: yes works ;very  thankyou